# NGXS - accessing parent state from child state

Tags: ngxs

I have a parent state composed of a child state :

```
 @State({
     name: 'parent',
     default: { parentProp : 'foo' },
     children: [
        ChildState,
     ]
 }) class ParentState {}
```

And a child state :

```
 @State({
     name: 'child',
     default: { },
 }) class ChildState {}
```

I would like to access `parentProp` inside ChildState, I tried with the [shared state method](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/shared-state) but it creates a circular dependency as ParentState imports ChildState and vis-versa.

Did I miss a simple solution ?

Comment: Have you looked at sub states? https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/sub-states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to put them in the same file to avoid the circular reference.

That being said, I would ask why the child is so interested in the parent property. Maybe that property could shift down to the child or the child could respond to the same action that the parent uses to set that property to capture its own copy of the value.

If you are looking for a way to create a selector across the two states then you could create a joining selector (see the relevant section here: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select).

Comment: How would you propose that the property *shift down to the child*, besides running another `@Action` in the child and copying the value as you suggest? Is there another method? I would really like to use join `@Selector`s here, but like the OP says it's impossible because of circular references.

Comment: Also I just realized, wouldn't this copying of values de-normalize the store?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same need as author. The reason why child would be interested in parent property is quite simple.
You focus here mainly on selecting part, but in my case I need it to keep clean files with state, where I'd like to avoid mess.

It's not my case, but corespond with it :). Let say we have main state with some properties and some child states keeping more complex data structure.

And now some action happens which set some valu in main state, then other happen which set something in child state, but I want to set  it f.e. in map with key as value of property from main state.

It's nothing spectacular... And such possibility probably would help a lot.